# Express API routes returning undefined response

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request

I'm using express to serve API endpoints to my redux app. When I attempt to make get requests from the client side to these endpoints, I get a response with `undefined` body property. When I use Postman to test the endpoint, it returns the expected result with a body property that is JSON data.

Here's my code

```js
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// var users = require('./routes/users');
var routes = require('./routes/index.js');

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
// app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')));

app.use('/', routes);
// app.use('/users', users);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// development error handler
// will print stacktrace
if (app.get('env') === 'development') {
  app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    res.status(err.status || 500);
    res.json({
      message: err.message,
      error: err
    });
  });
}

// production error handler
// no stacktraces leaked to user
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.json({
    message: err.message,
    error: {}
  });
});


module.exports = app;
```

Every other answer to this question says nothing more than "move the lines adding bodyParser middleware in front of the lines where you instantiate the routes", which I am already doing.

Comment: if it works from Postman but not your own client. The problem is mot likely not with the server but the request part in your action client side